# odoo10 how to build 2 onchange function in 1 field

Tags: python, odoo

I have problem with an `onchange` function in Odoo 10.

This is some example code:

```
class test_1(models.Model)
    Input = fields.Integer()
```

From another class, I have an `onchange` function. This class is a default system, which can't change or add anything in this code.

```
class test_onchange(models.Model)
    @api.onchange('Input')
    def _onchange_test_1(self):
        ## some process ##
```

Here is the function I am writing. It is an `onchange` with `Input` too.

```
class test_onchanger(models.Model)
    @api.onchange('Input')
    def _onchange_test_addon(self):
        ## some process. and different  _onchange_test_1
```

So the question is:

**How can I build an `onchange` function on the `Input` field from    another class/module if the `Input` field already has an `onchange`    function from the default system/code.**

Anyone have an idea? Can I inherit on `_onchange_test_1` or maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm, you want to *extend* (add customizations onto) an existing `onchange` method?

As mentioned in the other answer, the simplest way is to just inherit the existing `onchange` method.

---

Let's assume this is the core code, which you can't modify:

```
class CoreClass(models.Model):
    _name = 'core.class'

    Input = fields.Integer()

    @api.onchange('Input')
    def _onchange_input(self):
        ## some process ##
```

In your module, you can extend the class and make your additional changes.

*Note: The core class method still runs when you call it with `super`.*

```
class CoreClassCustom(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'core.class'

    @api.onchange('Input')
    def _onchange_input(self):
        res = super(CoreClassCustom, self)._onchange_input()
        ## your custom process ##
        return res
```

Here is [the Odoo 10 ORM Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields), which briefly goes over `onchange` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit existing onchange method or write another onchange method for same field, both will work.

Comment: Yeap, Can you just example code? now i try already but doesn't work.